# How can I target a specific Vimeo video when I have mulitple videos on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, vimeo-api

I have several videos embedded from Vimeo and I want to show an overlay with some information when you hover over the video.  The overlay blocks the play button, so I want the video to play when you click the overlay.  It works just fine with a single video, but I'm having trouble having the play command target the correct video when there are multiple videos.  Here's my script:

```
$(".overlay").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("playButton pauseButton");
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var iframe = document.getElementById("vimeo");
  var player = $f(iframe)
  var paused = player.api('paused()');

 var playButton = $(parent).children(".playButton");
 $(playButton).click( function () {
    player.api('play');
  });

  var pauseButton = $(parent).children(".pauseButton");
  $(pauseButton).click( function () {
    player.api('pause');
  });
});
```

The issue seems to be with this line

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("vimeo");
```

That pulls every video instead of just the one the overlay is associated with.  I've tried this:

```
var iframe = $(this).siblings("#vimeo");
```

But it doesn't seem to like jquery and I get an error.

Vimeo should probably be a class instead of an id, but I couldn't get it to work with any method other than getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add classes to each iframe to use for selecting the individual ones?

edited because my first suggestion was bad.

Comment: That's my backup plan.  Ideally this will end up as a wordpress template, so I won't be able to add new classes every time there's a new video, but if all else fails I'll probably end up doing that.

Comment: I mean honestly, if there are going to intentionally be multiple vimeo iframes on the same page, vimeo should be the class and each of them should have their own id because of this exact predicament.